# Need Xpath or CSSSelector locator for below HTML Code for a checkbox element

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

Need help with Xpath or CSSSelector locator for below HTML Code for a checkbox element. Checkbox element is present on the webpage with below URL :
    https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/basic-checkbox-demo.html

```
<div class="checkbox">
<label>
<input type="checkbox" class="cb1-element" value="">Option 1</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Xpath:

```
//label[text()='Option 1']/input
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Python, so in my case would look like this if I would use XPath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(.,'Option 1')]").click()
```

You can do like this if your page contains only one `Option 1` text